# how to create uitableview with different custom cells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UIImageView to place a picture there and  UITableView to place comments there. The part of the view with UIImageView should be scrolled with comment cells, that's why separate UIImageView and UITableView can't be used - the image won't be scrolled. If UIScrollView is used, than I receive scroll in scroll. Can cellForRowAtIndexPath method be used to create different cells? E.g.:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   CellWithImage * cell = (CellWithImage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithImage"];
   //some code here
   return cell;
}
else {
    CellWithComment * cell = (CellWithComment *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithComment"];
    //some code here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can do that. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not? Did you try it before posting the question?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, its better to make the imageview part of the header view for the section

Comment: Custom cells is not a good idea for this case.. Header views makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different identifiers to load different cell types and use them together inside the same table. In fact, your case is somewhat simple -- you're only using a different cell for the first row. You could easily choose the cell type based on the type of data that will be displayed in the row, position of data within a hierarchy, etc.